# Are parentheses needed around the returned object in an arrow function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

In the React docs, I came across this example of an arrow function.  After the =>, the state object is wrapped in parentheses.  Are they necessary?  And, if so, do the parentheses change how the arrow function works?

[image]

Different than?:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    //code
});
```

Would the code without the parentheses run properly?

Comment: (Did you try it?) Yes, you need parentheses if you intend to implicitly return an object, else it will be interpreted as the start of a function block, resulting in a syntax error. Putting parentheses around the `{}`s ensures that it's evaluated as an expression instead

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thank you.  That makes perfect sense.  I figured there was something obvious I was overlooking, and there was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code returns an object.

The longer version would be:

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
  return { counter: ... };
});
```